# Should I use .com as default suffix in email field?

Tags: usability

For example, if I have a landing page. Is a good approach an autocomplete with `.com` when the user start to write his email?

Most of email providers use `.com`, like hotmail ou gmail, but i am not sure if this is an improvement or not in the user experience.

Comment: Do you have problems with users submitting their email address without the TDL?  The .com TDL is the most commonly used in the U.S., but the *country* TDL is fairly common elsewhere (.ca, .co.uk, etc.).

Comment: It seems like an extremely minor convenience for some users, and an inconvenience for others. Are there other places to add value instead? For some folks (e.g. iPhone users) this will be handled by their OS, and for others their browser will be auto-filling the field anyway.

Comment: @cimmanon I'm sure you mean "TLD" and not "TDL" (Top Level Domain)

Comment: autocomplete for something like this is likely more annoying than helpful.

Comment: Statistically speaking, this will only help 53% of your users ([source](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/top_level_domain/all)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name the input for entering email as 'email' and a browser will try to autofill it from its history. Most users have probably entered their email into an input named 'email' on some other website.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say that it wouldn't be helpful in most cases. Let's consider the different input methods associated with form input - your assumption is that an email address is manually typed out. Starting with that, I think there's a little bit of overhead involved with autocompletion.

For example, if my address is nic@company.co.uk, I'm going to begin typing `nic@company.`, at which point I'd probably get my dropdown options for autocompletion. Based on the quantity of different TLDs, that could be more than a few. Think about `.com`, `.co.uk`, `.ca`, `.co.au`, and more - processing that list to find what I want seems like it would take longer than typing the 5 extra characters.

Additionally, email fields on mobile usually get some assistance from the keyboard, and this whole conversation is moot if autofill is used (which, by the way, would be good to know). Is it worth testing? Possibly, but I speculate that there won't be many advantages.

Answer (score 0):

You are bent on helping a user, you could write some logic that could auto fill the domain

Like when I am at example@example. and type c, you could try to auto fill using com, same way net for n so on. sample list of internet domains [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)

Comment: You could do, but `.co` and `.co.uk` start the same way. The amount of programming to produce *useful* autofill (like Excel does with lists in columns) would far outweigh the five characters the user wouldn't have to type.